# How to make docstring for pydantic class?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, pydantic

I search the best way to document clearly a class based on pydantic model and more globally a class with static attribut, for example :

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Point(BaseModel):
    """
    Class to represent a point

    :Example:

    .. code-block:: python

        >>> p = Point(x=123, y=142)

    :param int x: integer for x
    :param int y: integer for y
    """
    x: int
    y: int
```

if i generate the documentation with sphinx x and y attributs appears separatly...
for this class, a possible solution is to say ignore static attribut, but how ?

thanks.

Comment: "for this class, a possible solution is to say ignore static attribut, but how?" - Can you clarify what the problem is? Is there something special about Pydantic classes?